# My View won't update with updated data from my Angular5 component

Tags: angular, angular5

My view has some simple code:

```
  HERE{{ files.length }}THERE
  <div class="uploaded-files" *ngIf="files.length > 0">
    <div class="uploaded-files-title">
      <h4>Selected Files</h4><h5>&nbsp;(X)</h5>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">File Name</th>
        <th scope="col">File Size</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Upload Status</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center"><a href="" (click)="removeAll($event)">Remove All</a></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let file of files">
          <td>{{ file.relativePath }}</td>
          <td>{{file.size}}</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="mdi mdi-check-circle mdi-24px approved"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="mdi mdi-delete mdi-24px actions"></i></td>
        </tr>
```

My component is:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { UploadEvent, UploadFile, FileSystemFileEntry  } from 'ngx-file-drop';


@Component({
  selector: 'upload-modal',  // <upload-modal></upload-modal>
  providers: [
  ],
  styleUrls: [ './upload.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html'
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() {
  }

  public files: UploadFile[] = [];

  public ngOnInit() {
  }

  dropFile(event) {
    let droppedFiles: UploadFile[] = []
    if(this.files.length === 1) {
      return
    }

    const fileEntry = event.files[0].fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
    fileEntry.file(fileData => {
      console.log('before', this.files)
      this.files.push({
        name: fileEntry.name,
        size: fileData.size
      })
      console.log('after', this.files)
    })
  }

  handleFileInput() {
    alert('files')
  }

  removeAll(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    this.files: UploadFile[] = []
  }

}
```

When my component's `dropFile` function does what it does, the `console` prints out correctly, but the view doesn't have any updated files.

I'm using `angular 5.2.0`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you're *ngIf never changes to true to display the content? but you're console.log('after', this.files) shows that it has length greater than 0 is that correct?

Comment: @Woot that is correct.

Comment: am I correct in assuming the that Here {{ files.length }} There section of your code does display the correct length?

Comment: It does not. It shows 0

Comment: what triggers the dropFile function?  I don't see that in your component.  If that function isn't triggered by your component then I would guess that angular doesn't fire the change detection process when the function is called. Also I noticed that you component implements OnChanges but you don't import it and you don't implement it.  That could cause issues.

Comment: It's triggered from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have console errors? You’re defining your class to implement OnChanges but you are not implementing the method. Not sure how is this even compiling.

Comment: try that: `this.files = [...this.files, {
        name: fileEntry.name,
        size: fileData.size
      }]` instead of using `push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually detect changes using the change detection.  I don't recommend using this method in all situations but in this one it's probably the best way.

Add ChangeDectorRef to the import statement

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectorRef 
} from '@angular/core';
```

then add it to your constructor

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Then after you drop the files you can use the change detector to trigger change detection.

```
dropFile(event) {

  // add this to the end of the dropFile method
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Angular's not aware of you having changed the model behind the scenes.

By default, Angular uses [zones](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#zone) to trigger it's change detection mechanism after async events—although this works fine for most async events you'll encounter, the zone implementation used by Angular, Zone.js, only supports a handful of non-standard APIs and [FileSystemFileEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry) isn't [one of them](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/dffae8b6f528c84ec18a24a179b1d0760436e35b/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md). In cases like this, your best bet is to manually trigger the change detection as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular).

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop to get the `FileSystemFileEntry`. I tried with zones - no dice.

Comment: It's strange that manually triggering the change detection's not working—in the [official demo](https://georgipeltekov.github.io/) of the library they do exactly and it looks like it's working fine.

Comment: If you to it like in the official demo i.e. inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` into the `constructor` and call it's `detectChanges()` method in the last line in the `file` callback (**not** the last line of your `dropFile` method) I think it should work fine. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The change detector needs to be the last line of the callback as user4091335 pointed out and not the last line of the droppped file method.

```
dropped(event: any) {
    for (const droppedFile of event.files) {
      const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
      fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
        this.files.push(file);
        **this.ref.detectChanges();**
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to update the view, and I solved using promises instead of detecting the changes on the view using ChangeDetectorRef. Worked like a charm. 
Here's my solution

```
    triggerUpload(evt:UploadEvent){    


    let files = evt.files;
    let self = this;
    this.fillupFiles(files).then(function(response){
       self.uploadAndRender();          
    });

  }

fillupFiles(files):Promise<Object>{
    let self = this;
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var count = files.length;
      var index = 0;
      for(let droppedFile of files){
        if(droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile){
          let fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
          fileEntry.file((file:File)=>{
            index++;
            self.files.push(file);
            if(index==count){
              resolve(true);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

    return promise;
  }
```